# MIDI Note On Event Without Off Event

Tags: midi

I made a system that takes MIDI files and creates a graphical representation of the music.
Every `NoteOnEvent` is when a single note starts, and every `NoteOffEvent`with the same note code is when it ends.

This works well for most MIDI files.

However, I am now encountering files that do not have `NoteOffEvent` events at all, and so I keep playing them.

What is the correct behavior when seeing for example:

```
midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=0, channel=0, data=[65, 127])
midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=240, channel=0, data=[65, 0])
```

I think if a note "on" event happens on the same note it should be like a toggle event, but I am not sure what if it is justified, or does this even happen for every midi file or just a subset that act like this?

**EDIT:**
I don't think this matters, but I am using `python-midi` to extract the tracks from midi files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common for a note on with 0 velocity to be interpreted as note off. I am not sure if it's part of the standard or not.

Comment: That makes absolute sense and does generalize for both on and off cases. Thank you. None official reference to confirm - https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=291892

Comment: Yes, it's part of the standard.  Here's part of it reproduced:  http://www.lim.di.unimi.it/IEEE/MIDI/SOT1.HTM#Off-

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @brad

Comment: THANK YOU BROTHER !!! No its not and all parsers ignore this and I was stuck on this some alsmost a day debugging tying figuring out what to do..